# Can Operations be attacked in Pixel Tactics?

Tags: pixel-tactics

In Pixel Tactics 2 and some other versions, there are Operations (Ongoing Orders) that sit in the reserve spot of your unit. Do these count as heroes that can be attacked, or are they there for 4 Waves no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attack Operations. They are not part of your unit and only reside in one of 3 reserve slots which hold only Traps or Operations. Neither can be directly attacked as they have no attack or health.

On the other hand, some cards can increase or decrease the amount of timers on various Operations. In this way, you can lengthen or reduce the time an Operation is in play even though it cannot be removed directly.